# Why is it so difficult to find instructions for upgrading from 11.10 to 12.04?

Tags: upgrade, release-upgrade

My update manager had a link to upgrade my entire system displayed above the usual list of recommended patches/updates, so I thought I'd save time and opt for that upgrade.

Unfortunately, I lost my connection to the server (so it seemed) half-way through.  It looked like it managed to download everything, but then it simply hung for hours and now that I've rebooted I no longer see the "offer" to upgrade to 12 - yet I'm still running 11.  I can't find my way to anything - either locally on this host or on the Ubuntu web site.  The [major page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OneiricOcelot) for 11.10 offers a link to guide one to upgrade to it, not past it, yet the corresponding "[major page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin)" for 12.04 doesn't include similar, or look anything like its predecessor.  In fact, it seems rather half-baked.

Obviously there are lots of folks suffering with some sort of problems upgrading, but so far I'm not finding any useful info wading through their threads, either.  This has wasted an inordinate amount of time already, with no sign of my even getting near the scent, much less treeing the varmint.  If I was an Apple baby I'd have given up long ago!

Comment: I don't really understand the question here, what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean this? The first hit from a Google search of "upgrade ubuntu". http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade Did you check for updates?

You can also do:

- [How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-from-10-04-or-11-10-to-12-04)